# iphone navigation tutorial with simple form

Tags: iphone

I'm looking to create quite a basic app with a very simple navigation system but each of the tutorials I've come across so far go into too much depth or just involve lots of different form elements. I want to keep it as straight forward and simple as I can.

If anyone knows of any tutorials that can show me how to create a root view with say 5 or 6 sub views each displaying a form for collecting different types of data I would be very grateful. This seems like quite a simple thing to achieve but so far I havent found anything that specifically relates to what I want to do.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This would normally be blatant advertising but a new app that will be released soon will automatically generate this code for you -  [Dapp - the app design app](http://dapp.kerofrog.com.au).

You can then look at the code, see how it's done and make changes where needed.  The blog also has a simple Hello World tutorial that can give you a quick look at how the code generation works.

Apart from that, I could write a standard tutorial.  But it might go into too much depth or involve too many form elements :).

Comment: This looks very interesting, it probably won't be perfect but it definitely will be useful. thanks a lot Raal

Comment: Dapp will generate the Navigation Controller, App Delegates, View Controllers, Views and main.m file for you.  It will then link the Navigation Controller to your first View Controller + View. :)  

The next version of Dapp (estimated release May 26) will give the option to generate a TableViewController with a list of all the views you created in Dapp.  Clicking on any of them will push that view controller + view.  :)